# How to inject dependencies in Blazor Web Assembly using Grpc and protobuf-net

Tags: protobuf-net, blazor-client-side, grpc-web, blazor-webassembly

I am building a Web Assembly Blazor with Grpc using protobuf-net to handle the services. I am trying to inject the Service I want this way:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(ICustomerService), services =>
        {
            // Create a gRPC-Web channel pointing to the backend server
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(new GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb, new HttpClientHandler()));
            var channel = Grpc.Net.Client.GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001", new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpClient = httpClient });

            // Now we can instantiate gRPC clients for this channel
            return channel.CreateGrpcService<ICustomerService>();
        });
```

Then, I inject what I think should be the dependecy into the razor component:

```
[Inject] ICustomerService Client { get; set; }
```

But I get this error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot provide a value for property 'Client' on type 'Customer_Create'. There is no registered service of type 'ICustomerService'.

Any help here is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this specifically in blazor, but in general: you're looking for the [Client Factory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net.Grpc.ClientFactory/) support, which works [exactly like documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/clientfactory?view=aspnetcore-3.1) except you register with the `AddCodeFirstGrpcClient` method:

```cs
services.AddCodeFirstGrpcClient<IMyService>(o =>
{
    o.Address = new Uri("...etc...");
});
```